# Issue with shadows/Opacity on sprites in cocos2d (.png format)

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, png, opacity, photoshop

I'm having trouble understanding why sprites with shadows (%opacity layer) looks different in ps and on screen. Here is the comparison:

[image: iOS Simulator (same on device)]

[image: Photoshop]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply because of image formate you set. I guess you set RGBA4444 in code or while exporting spriteSheet. Also remove checkmark Premultiply alpha in texture packer.

[image]

Also check in AppDelegate Class:

```
CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:[window_ bounds]
                                   pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8 //Guru - replaced kEAGLColorFormatRGB565 with kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                                   depthFormat:0    //GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES
                            preserveBackbuffer:NO
                                    sharegroup:nil
                                 multiSampling:NO
                               numberOfSamples:0];
[CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];
```